# To add a function value into firestore using cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

This is the function which returns player name from 3rd party api and i want to store the value which this function is returning into my firestore database(matchList/matchData) as a player name field using cloud function.

```
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    port: null,
    path: "/scorecards.php?seriesid=2141&matchid=43431",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
    },
    json: true
  };
  var req = http.request(options, res => {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", chunk => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      playerName = json.fullScorecardAwards.manOfTheMatchName;
      console.log("player name", playerName);
      response.send(playerName);
    });
  });
  req.end();
}
```

Comment: Please someone help me as i am new to cloud functions. Thank you

Comment: What did u try, in your code u didn't store it in the database

Comment: yes.i am unable to store playerName variable value in my firestore database using cloud function.

Comment: i get the data from this api and store that data into playerName variable. Now i want to store this variable value into my firestore database whose path is:- Match/matchData. In matchData document i want to store this variable value under the field "playerName:" by using cloud function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First download the following:

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Then initialize cloud firestore:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let db = admin.firestore();
```

Then to store the value do the following:

```
let docRef = db.collection('match').doc('matchData');

let setPlayer = docRef.set({playerName : playerName});
```

Check the following for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: But how can i used this inside a cloud function?

Comment: Can i used like this : exports.storeMatchData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {//The above mentioned code}

Comment: You need to read the documents I shared, first configure the cloud function then the code I gave you write it after `playerName = json.fullScorecardAwards.manOfTheMatchName;`. After that line write `let docRef = db.collection('match').doc('matchData');

let setPlayer = docRef.set({playerName : playerName});`

Answer (score -1):

While it can be argued Firebase/Firestore/Cloud Functions are all part of the same family, the question was how to specifically use Firestore and Cloud Functions under the GCP banner.

From the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-firestore

```js
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
// Use your project ID here
const PROJECTID = '[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]';
const COLLECTION_NAME = 'cloud-functions-firestore';

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: PROJECTID,
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
  // NOTE: Don't hardcode your project credentials here.
  // If you have to, export the following to your shell:
  //   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path>
  // keyFilename: '/cred/cloud-functions-firestore-000000000000.json',
});

/**
* Retrieve or store a method in Firestore
*
* Responds to any HTTP request.
*
* GET = retrieve
* POST = store (no update)
*
* success: returns the document content in JSON format & status=200
*    else: returns an error:<string> & status=404
*
* @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
* @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
*/
exports.main = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // store/insert a new document
    const data = (req.body) || {};
    const ttl = Number.parseInt(data.ttl);
    const ciphertext = (data.ciphertext || '')
      .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_!.,; ']*/g, '')
      .trim();
    const created = new Date().getTime();

    // .add() will automatically assign an ID
    return firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).add({
      created,
      ttl,
      ciphertext
    }).then(doc => {
      console.info('stored new doc id#', doc.id);
      return res.status(200).send(doc);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(404).send({
        error: 'unable to store',
        err
      });
    });
  }

  // everything below this requires an ID
  if (!(req.query && req.query.id)) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      error: 'No II'
    });
  }
  const id = req.query.id.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').trim();
  if (!(id && id.length)) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      error: 'Empty ID'
    });
  }

  if (req.method === 'DELETE') {
    // delete an existing document by ID
    return firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
      .doc(id)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        return res.status(200).send({ status: 'ok' });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(404).send({
          error: 'unable to delete',
          err
        });
      });
  }

  // read/retrieve an existing document by ID
  return firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!(doc && doc.exists)) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          error: 'Unable to find the document'
        });
      }
      const data = doc.data();
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          error: 'Found document is empty'
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(404).send({
        error: 'Unable to retrieve the document',
        err
      });
    });
};
```